# I changed the folder structure of my dotnet core 5 app and now my dockerfile is wrong

Tags: docker, heroku, .net-core, dockerfile

I created a new dotnetcore 5.0 application and got it running in Heroku with docker. Later, I added some projects and needed to reorganize a bit, so I pushed the main .csproj into a subfolder. I'm assuming this is what broke my docker deploy. Here is my original dockerfile that was working:

```
    FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build-env
    WORKDIR /app
    
    COPY *.csproj ./
    RUN dotnet restore
    
    COPY . .
    RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out
    
    FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0
    WORKDIR /app
    COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
    
    
    CMD ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:$PORT dotnet my-app.dll
```

This is my folder structure (roughly)

```
* my-app.sln
* Dockerfile
* Api
    - my-application.csproj <= main project
    - Program.cs
    - Startup.cs
* Application
    - application.csproj <= class library
* Database
    - database.csproj <= class library
```

This is the error I get:

```
    Step 3/10 : COPY *.csproj ./
    
    COPY failed: no source files were specified
```

I'm assuming that I've made it impossible for docker to find the right files and copy them to the right places, but I've tried at least a dozen different ways of copying and writing the paths and I'm just not having any luck. Can anyone help me understand what my docker file should look like?

Comment: `COPY *.csproj ./` there is no more `csproj` files at the same level as your Dockerfile. Either `*/*.csproj` or remove it because you are either way doing `COPY . .` after.

Comment: Changing it to `COPY */*.csproj ./` fixes Step 3! Thank you!. But then I run into an issue in Step 4: `Specify which project or solution file to use because this folder contains more than one project or solution file.` I tried appending `./app/Api/my-app.csproj` to line 5, but it's telling me the project doesn't exist

Comment: Nevermind, got past that as well with `RUN dotnet publish ./my-app.sln -c Release -o out`, now I'm trying to get past the `publish` command

Answer (score 0):

***new answer***

I think you can get away with single `Dockerfile` as well. This is what my multi-project solution looks like.

[image]

I hoisted Dockerfile at the solution level.

Individual `.csproj` files sits inside the respective folder.

The `Dockerfile.api` file looks like below:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["MovieAPI/MovieAPI.csproj", "MovieAPI/"]
COPY ["Models/Models.csproj", "Models/"]
COPY ["DAL/DAL.csproj", "DAL/"]
COPY ["Core/Core.csproj", "Core/"]
RUN dotnet restore "MovieAPI/MovieAPI.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/MovieAPI"
RUN dotnet build "MovieAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MovieAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MovieAPI.dll"]
```

***previous answer***

Rules of thumb: `Dockerfile` and `.csproj` files are supposed to be at the same level.

When you have multiple `Dockerfile`s multiple projects and solution files an easy way out is to create a `docker-compose` file at the solution level and reference the Dockerfile in the `docker-compose.yml` and use the `dockerfile` tag in the `docker-compose.yml` to point to correct `Dockerfile`

#### Folder Structure:

There are multiple `docker-compose.yml` along side `.sln` file and each folder has multiple sub folders with their own `Dockerfile`
[image]

#### `docker-compose` like below:

version: '3.4'

services:
sqldata:
image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest

nosqldata:
image: mongo

identity-api:
image: ${REGISTRY:-eshop}/identity.api:${PLATFORM:-linux}-${TAG:-latest}
build:
context: .
dockerfile: Services/Identity/Identity.API/Dockerfile

webhooks-client:
image: ${REGISTRY:-eshop}/webhooks.client:${PLATFORM:-linux}-${TAG:-latest}
build:
context: .
dockerfile: Web/WebhookClient/Dockerfile

#### source:

https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers

Refer this project for complex arrangement of `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml`.

Comment: This seems like a really great answer, but I am just not understanding some fundamentals about this whole thing I think. I don't really understand what the docker-compose is doing, or more importantly, how to tell Heroku to use it. I'm really confused about how having multiple projects is even throwing things for a loop. It's just the API project and then two libraries that it depends on. Do they each need their own dockerfile? They aren't deployed separately or anything.

Comment: I got a little farther by moving the dockerfile into the Api folder, but having build issues I assume because it's just not building the other two projects

Comment: Sorry if I confused you. Not sure about Heroku based projects. But I added a new answer. Does this help?

Comment: Docker Compose: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volume-configuration-reference